# Run eslint loader in node_modules of one particular folder which is npm linked and non compiled one

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, eslint

By using webpack 4 i am able to run eslint across the project folder using this configuration

```
    {
      enforce: 'pre',
      test: /\.js|ts$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'eslint-loader'
    },
```

Now i want to run eslint in node_modules of one particular folder which is npm linked and non compiled one, for that i used some regular expression like this

```
    {
      enforce: 'pre',
      test: /\.js|ts$/,
      exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(my-folder)\/).*/,
      loader: 'eslint-loader'
     },
```

it didn't worked. suggest me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I find the following approach works well and is both readable and maintainable

```
// webpack.config.js 
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js|ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader'
      },
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js|ts$/,
        include: /node_modules\/my-folder/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: still its not linting the node_modules/my-folder

Comment: I got the thing by creating  .eslintignore file  with this line of code !node_modules/my-folder and  config like this {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js|ts$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader'
      }